# Quaternionic and octonionic analogues of the Basel problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, quaternions, octonions, complex-multiplication

It is a well-known fact that

$$\sum_{0\neq n\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{n^k} = r_k (2\pi)^k$$

for any integer $k>1$, where $r_k$ are rational numbers which can be given explicitly in terms of Bernoulli numbers. For example, for $k=2$ the sum equals $\pi^2/3$ (this is essentially the [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem)), and for $k=4$ it equals $\pi^4/45$. Note that for odd $k$ the sum vanishes.

The theory of [elliptic curves with complex multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_multiplication) allows us to extend this result to systems of complex integers such as the [Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer), or more generally the ring of integers in an imaginary quadratic number field of class number 1. Namely, for $k>2$ we have

$$\sum_{0\neq \lambda\in\mathbb{Z[\omega]}} \frac{1}{\lambda^k} = r_k \varpi^k,$$

where again $r_k$ are rational constants and $\varpi \in \mathbb{R}$ (the "complex $2\pi$") depends only on the ring $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z[\omega]}$ and is an algebraic multiple of a so-called [Chowla–Selberg period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chowla%E2%80%93Selberg_formula), given by a product of powers of certain gamma factors (note that the sum is always a real number since it is invariant under conjugation). For example, for the [Eisenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer) ($\omega = (1+\sqrt{3} i)/2$), Gaussian ($\omega = i$) and [Kleinian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleinian_integer) ($\omega = (1+\sqrt{7} i)/2$) integers, we have respectively

$$\varpi_3 = 3^{-1/4} \sqrt{2\pi} \left(\frac{\Gamma(1/3)}{\Gamma(2/3)}\right)^{3/2}, \quad \varpi_4 = 4^{-1/4} \sqrt{2\pi} \left(\frac{\Gamma(1/4)}{\Gamma(3/4)}\right), \quad \varpi_7 = 7^{-1/4} \sqrt{2\pi} \left(\frac{\Gamma(1/7)\Gamma(2/7)\Gamma(4/7)}{\Gamma(3/7)\Gamma(5/7)\Gamma(6/7)}\right)^{1/2}.$$

For higher class numbers there is a similar formula, though in that case $r_k$ will in general not be rational but algebraic. A nice exposition of this result can be found in Section 6.3 of [these notes](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/978-3-540-74119-0_1/fulltext.pdf).

---

My question is whether this is still true for hypercomplex number systems, such as the [Hurwitz integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_quaternion) or the [octonionic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion#Integral_octonions).  Define $$S_k[\mathcal{O}] = \sum_{0\neq \lambda\in\mathcal{O}} \frac{1}{\lambda^k}$$ for $k>\operatorname{dim} \mathcal{O}$, where $\mathcal{O}$ is now an order in a totally definite rational quaternion/octonion algebra of class number 1. The restriction on $k$ is so that the sum converges absolutely.

> **Subquestion 1:** Do we have $S_k[\mathcal{O}] = r_k \varpi^k$ for some rational sequence $r_k$ and some real number $\varpi$ depending only on $\mathcal{O}$ (a "quaternionic/octonionic $2\pi$")?

Obviously $\varpi$ will only be defined up to a nonzero rational factor. An equivalent question is whether $(S_m[\mathcal{O}])^n/(S_n[\mathcal{O}])^m$ is rational for any $m, n$ such that $S_n[\mathcal{O}]\neq 0$.

> **Subquestion 2:** If so, can (some fixed choice of) $\varpi$ be expressed in terms of
> known constants such as $\zeta'(-1)$ or $\zeta'(-3)$?

The reason I'm mentioning these particular constants is that in the previous cases (real and complex) the period $\varpi$ turns out to be equal to $e^{-\zeta'(\mathcal{O},0)/\zeta(\mathcal{O},0)}$ up to an algebraic factor, where the zeta function attached to the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z[\omega]}$ is defined as

$$\zeta(\mathcal{O},s) = \sum_{0\neq \lambda\in\mathcal{O}} |\lambda|^{-s}.$$

(This is in general not the same as the previous sums, note the absolute value). In the case that $\mathcal{O}$ is instead a quaternionic or octonionic order, the logarithmic derivative of this zeta function at $s=0$ can be expressed in terms of $\zeta'(-1)$ or $\zeta'(-3)$ respectively, where $\zeta(s)$ is the ordinary Riemann zeta function.

---

**Update:** I have calculated a few sums numerically for the ring of Hurwitz quaternions. The result is $$S_6[\mathcal{O}] \approx 10.76,\quad S_8[\mathcal{O}] \approx 1.196,\quad S_{12}[\mathcal{O}] \approx 23.9905.$$

Unfortunately the calculations take a lot of time, and right now the precision is not senough to determine whether e.g. $S_{12}[\mathcal{O}]/(S_6[\mathcal{O}])^2$ is rational to any degree of confidence.

Comment: There is probably too much moduli space and automorphic representations hidden in there to not move to mathoverflow.net

Comment: Following reuns's advice, I decided to ask this question at MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372677/quaternionic-and-octonionic-analogues-of-the-basel-problem).